# ShareKit assert: "ShareKit has been refactored to be used as Xcode subproject."

Tags: ios, objective-c, assert, git-submodules, sharekit

I'm having trouble getting [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) to work in my app. I've followed the latest installation instructions, creating a submodule for ShareKit, and tried cleaning and rebuilding, deleting and replacing the submodule, and so on. But when I try to create an `SHKActionSheet` I get this assert:

> 2013-03-03 15:48:39.998 Symmetry Lab[4170:907] *** Assertion failure
>   in NSString *SHKLocalizedStringFormat(NSString *)(),
>   /Users/lukebradford/Apps/Symmetry
>   Lab/Submodules/ShareKit/Classes/ShareKit/Core/SHK.m:811 2013-03-03
>   15:48:40.004 Symmetry Lab[4170:907] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'ShareKit has been refactored to be used as Xcode subproject. Please
>   follow the updated installation wiki and re-add it to the project.
>   Please do not forget to clean project and clean build folder
>   afterwards. In case you use CocoaPods override - (NSNumber
>   *)isUsingCocoaPods; method in your configurator subclass and return [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]'

I've used ShareKit for other apps without issues with both the old and new installation method. Has anyone run into anything similar or have a suspicion as to what could be causing this?

I don't do anything crazy with ShareKit, just set my custom configurator and then launch an action sheet with an image. Thanks for any help you might be able to offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of sharekit are you using? Are you using the newest version (which they're calling "2.0") from https://github.com/ShareKit/ ? I recently used that in a project, and had all kinds of pain until I realized that the version most turned up on the web (http://getsharekit.com) is a big bag of hurt with current iOS.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the newest version, straight from GitHub.

Comment: Ah, don't know then. Can only state the obvious: either you have bug I don't recognize, or despite your best intentions you've missed or slightly miscued something in the process of installing into your project. Without further details showing the state of your project configuration I'm unable to help. Perhaps someone more helpful will recognize the error message....

Comment: Damn, I just missed the Copy Bundle Resources step! Blah.